# How to SELECT DISTINCT on 1 key column when querying multiple columns

Tags: sql-server

I am working in SQL Server 2008 R2.  I have a table in which 1 "record" is actually several records due to one of its fields having different values.  This table has a lot of fields itself.  All of the fields for a given "record" will have the same value, except for the one field that has various values.  I want to query all records and return all fields, but I want only 1 instance (the first one) of each "record".  For example, my table looks like:

```
Field 1    Field 2       Field 3
value a    value x       value 1
value a    value x       value 2
value a    value x       value 3
value b    value y       value 20
value b    value y       value 21
value b    value y       value 22
```

I want my query to return something like:

```
Field 1    Field 2       Field 3
value a    value x       value 1
value b    value y       value 20
```

So, my Field 1 is my key.  Normally, I would just do a SELECT DISTINCT.  However, since I want all fields to return in the query, the DISTINCT will apply to all of the fields in the SELECT, which means that all records will return, rather than just 1 for each key.  What is the best way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Please, they are called **columns**, not *fields*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t.field1,t.field2,t.field3 FROM
(
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION by Field1 ORDER BY Field1) AS RowNumber
FROM mytable
) t
WHERE t.RowNumber = 1
```

This method only looks at the distinct aspect of the first column. Order is not guaranteed in SQL. You can set how you define your "First Row" with the "ORDER BY" section of the above code.

Comment: Correct answer. If you have an identity column in the table use that as your OrderBy to get the "first" row in the result set.

Comment: I like the added control with this solution.  Unfortunately, as I begin to investigate my columns some more, it turns out there are other fields that behave like Field 3.  (I have about 100 fields in all in the table.)  So, I will have to identify all of them and exclude them from the partition.

Comment: Essentially, I am trying to emulate the "Remove Duplicates" feature in Excel, where all I would have to do is activate the checkbox for Field 1.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you want the minimum value from Field 3:

```
SELECT [Field 1], [Field 2], MIN([Field 3])
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY [Field 1], [Field 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to group by Field 1 & Field 2 and then take the min of Field 3.

```
select      [Field 1],
            [Field 2],
            MIN([Field 3]) as [Field 3]
from        [SomeTable]
group by    [Field 1], [Field 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Group By` over `field 1` and `field 2`;